# Tweaking an object created in setup() in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm new to Processing, and I am trying to work with the Tweaking tool. My problem is that I can't seem to be able to tweak the values of variables created in the `setup()` method.

Below, an example:

```
Ellipse e;

void setup(){
  size(640, 480);
  e = new Ellipse();
}

void draw(){
  background(220);
  e.draw();
}

class Ellipse {
  float w, l; 

  Ellipse(){
    this.w = 300.0;
    this.l = 300.0;
  }

  void draw(){
    ellipse(300, 300 , w, l);
  }
}
```

When I use "Tweak", I can tweak all four instances of `300` in the `Ellipse` class. It works exactly as expected for the 3rd and 4th ones, but when I tweak the values of `w` or `l`, nothing happens.

I assume this is because the `Ellipse` object is created from `setup()` and not `draw()`. Is this the right diagnostic, and is there a way around the problem? (I don't want to create a brand new object at every call of `draw()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only changes you'll see are when you change numbers **that haven't happened yet**.

Your `Ellipse` has already been constructed, so changing the values of `300` in the constructor won't do anything. Note that if you were to create a **new** instance of `Ellipse`, then that new instance would indeed pick up the changes.

You are able to tweak the first two `300` values because they "happen" every frame.

If you want to be able to tweak the `w` and `l` variables, you need to put them in a place that happens every frame. You could do something like this:

```
  void draw(){
    w = 300;
    l = 300;
    ellipse(300, 300 , w, l);
  }
```

Or you could just shorten it to this:

```
  void draw(){
    ellipse(300, 300 , 300, 300);
  }
```

From the [TweakMode homepage](http://galsasson.com/tweakmode/):

> **Scope of change**
>
> Without going into too much detail of how tweak mode operates
>   internally, you should remember that changing a number will have
>   effect only if the tweaked code will be executed in the future. For
>   example, take the following code:
>
> ```
> void setup()
> {
>   size(200, 200);
>   background(20);
> }
>
> void draw()
> {
>   fill(100, 0, 0);
>   ellipse(100, 100, 50, 50);
> }
> ```
>
> In this code, changing the values of 'size(...)' and 'background(...)'
>   functions will have no effect while the sketch is running because
>   these lines of code happened once on setup and will never be executed
>   again during the sketch life. On the contrary, changing the values of
>   fill() and ellipse() will have effect because 'draw' is executed over
>   and over again.
>
> The same principle applies to global variables, for example:
>
> ```
> int CIRCLE_SIZE = 50;
>
> void setup()
> {
>   size(200, 200);
>   background(20);
> }
>
> void draw()
> {
>   int red = 100;
>   fill(red, 0, 0);
>   ellipse(100, 100, CIRCLE_SIZE, CIRCLE_SIZE);
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, changing the value assigned to CIRCLE_SIZE (50) will
>   have no effect because the assignment of the value '50' to the
>   variable CIRCLE_SIZE happened only once during the sketch life, so the
>   value of CIRCLE_SIZE will remain the same even if the assigned value
>   is changed. On the contrary, changing the assigned value of the
>   variable 'red' (100) will have the expected effect because this
>   assignment happens every draw.
>
> A simple solution to the problem with the global variables is to
>   reassign values you wish to tweak in the draw function. For example,
>   the following draw function will elliminate the issue we had with the
>   size of the ellipse in the previous code.
>
> ```
> void draw()
> {
>   CIRCLE_SIZE = 50;
>   int red = 100;
>   fill(red, 0, 0);
>   ellipse(100, 100, CIRCLE_SIZE, CIRCLE_SIZE);
> }
> ```
>
> Adding the line 'CIRCLE_SIZE = 50;' to the top of the draw function
>   made it possible to tweak this number and control also the size of the
>   circle in real time.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth No problem. I've never seen TweakMode before, so this was a cool discovery for me.